# The method "handlesignup" is not been callled by browser console when deployed . can you check my code once?

Tags: lightning-web-components, method, javascript-debugging

Here is the html part

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Customer Sign Up">
        <div class="slds-p-around_medium">
            <lightning-input label="Username" type="text" value={username} onchange={handleUsernameChange}></lightning-input>
            <lightning-input label="Password" type="password" value={password} onchange={handlePasswordChange}></lightning-input>
            <lightning-input label="Email" type="email" value={email} onchange={handleEmailChange}></lightning-input>
            <lightning-input label="Aadhar Number" type="aadharnumber" value={aadharnumber} onchange={handleAadharnumberChange}></lightning-input>
            <lightning-input label="Contact Number" type="contactnumber" value={contactnumber} onchange={handleContactnumberChange}></lightning-input>
            <lightning-button label="Sign Up" variant="brand" onclick={handleSignUp}></lightning-button>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

And here is my .JS part

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import createCustomerRecord from '@salesforce/apex/CustomerController.createCustomerRecord';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
export default class CustomerSignup extends LightningElement {
    @track username = '';
    @track password = '';
    @track email = '';
    @track aadharnumber = '';
    @track contactnumber = '';
    customer = [];
    handleUsernameChange(event) {
        this.username = event.target.value;
    }

    handlePasswordChange(event) {
        this.password = event.target.value;
    }

    handleEmailChange(event) {
        this.email = event.target.value;
    }
    handleAadharnumberChange(event) {
        this.aadharnumber = event.target.value;
    }
    handleContactnumberChange(event) {
        this.contactnumber = event.target.value;
    }


    handleSignUp() {
        this.customer.username = this.username
        this.customer.password = this.password
        this.customer.email = this.email
        this.customer.aadharnumber = this.aadharnumber
        this.customer.contactnumber = this.contactnumber




        // Create customer record using Apex method
        if (this.username != null && this.password != null && email != null && this.aadharnumber != null && this.contactnumber != null) 
        {
            createCustomerRecord({ username: this.username, password: this.password, email: this.email, aadharnumber: this.aadharnumber, contactnumber: this.contactnumber })
                .then(result => {
                    // Handle success
                    console.log('Customer record created:', result);
                    //success message
                    // Perform any additional actions or navigate to another page
                    const toastEvent = new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Success',
                        message: 'Sign up successful!',
                        variant: 'success',
                    });
                    this.dispatchEvent(toastEvent);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    // Handle error
                    console.error('Error creating customer record:', error);
                    // Display error message to the user
                    const toastEvent = new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Error',
                        message: 'An error occurred while creating the customer record',
                        variant: 'error',
                    });
                    this.dispatchEvent(toastEvent);
                });
        }
        else {
            const toastEvent = new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Warning',
                message: 'Please fill in all the required fields',
                variant: 'warning',
              });
              this.dispatchEvent(toastEvent);
            }
        }
}
```

I am also adding the class :

```
public with sharing class CustomerController {
    /*public class Customer {
        @AuraEnabled
        public String username { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled
        public String password { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled
        public String email { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled
        public String aadharnumber { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled
        public String contactnumber { get; set; }
    }*/

    @AuraEnabled
    public static void createCustomerRecord(String username, String password,String email ,String aadharnumber ,String contactnumber){       // Perform any necessary validations on the input fields
        //Customer cst = (Customer)JSON.deserialize(customerrecord,customer.class );
        //system.debug('somankar'+cst);
        // Create a new customer record
        CUSTOMER__c newCustomer = new CUSTOMER__c();
        newCustomer.Full_Name__c = username;
        newCustomer.New_Password__c = password;
        newCustomer.Email_Adress__c = email;
        newCustomer.Aadhar_Number__c = aadharnumber;
        newCustomer.Contact_Number__c = contactnumber;
        
        // Insert the new customer record
        try {
            insert newCustomer;
            //System.debug('Customer record created successfully: ' + newCustomer);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug('Error creating customer record: ' + e.getMessage());
            throw new AuraHandledException('Error creating customer record');
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for too much comment part . Thanks in advance .